# how to get a specific number out from span class in python by using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

how to get a specific number out from span class in python by using selenium?

```
<button class="sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    " type="button">외 <span>59</span>명</button>
```

I want to get "59"

```
<button class="sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    " type="button">좋아요 <span>247</span>개</button>
```

I want to get "24"

below is my code

```
try:
        like_css = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            "button.sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5")
        if like_css.text == "좋아요":
            like_number = 0
        else:
            like_text = like_css.text[4:-1]
            like_number = int(like_text.replace(",", ""))

    except NoSuchElementException:
        like_number = 0
```

my code can get 24 from `<button class="sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    " type="button">좋아요 <span>247</span>개</button>`

but it gets ' ' from `<button class="sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    " type="button">외 <span>59</span>명</button>`

Answer (score 0):

i fix my code

```
 try:
        like_css = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5>span")
        like_text = like_css.text
        if like_text == "좋아요":
            like_number = 0
        else:
            like_number = int(like_text.replace(",",""))

    except NoSuchElementException:
        like_number = 0
```